# Sort props.put JS

Tags: javascript

I have never worked with javascript. I need to sort the entries in a drop-down menu alphabetically.

Let me give you the complete picture. There are other drop-down selections that lead to the drop-down that I am trying to sort alphabetically:

First one has a selection of two values:

engg

med

===============================================================

This is passed to the second script as varialble "courseFamily":

```
var result = new Properties();
if(!courseFamily){
    return result;
}
if(courseFamily == "engg"){
    result.put("comp","Computers")
    result.put("it","Information Technology")
    result.put("mech","Mechanical")
    result.put("entc","Electronics and Telecommunications")
    result.put("elct","Electrical")
}else{
    result.put("MBBS","Bachelor of Medicine")
    result.put("DDS","Dentistry")
    result.put("DO","Osteopathic medicine")
   }
return result
```

===============================================================

The result "specialization" is passed to the third script, which takes inputs from both the above scripts, courseFamily and specialization:

```
var result = new Properties()
if (!courseFamily ||!specialization) {
    return result;
}
if(courseFamily == "engg"){
return System.getModule("com.xyz").Engg_specialization(specialization);

}else{
   return System.getModule("com.xyz").Med_specialization(specialization);
}
```

===============================================================

This calls the script that gives the drop down, that I want to sort alphabetically:

```
var props = new Properties();
if (courseName == "comp")
{
props.put("co","Computer Organization")
props.put("ds","Data Structures")
props.put("os","Operating Systems")

}
else if (courseName == "elct")
{
 props.put("adec", "Analog and Digital Electrical Circuits");    
 props.put("ct", "Circuit Theory");
 props.put("pedc", "Power Electronics Devices and Circuits");

}  
else if (courseName == "mech")
{
  props.put("ht", "Heat Transfer");
  props.put("kas", "Kinematic Analysis and Synthesis");
  props.put("md", "Machine Drawing");
  props.put("mse", "Material Science and Engineering");
}
else{
    props.put("error", "Course Not Available ")
}
return props;
```

===============================================================

The drop-down menu doesn't show the entries in the order given in the code. I need to ensure that the entries in the drop-down are arranged alphabetically.

What changes can I make to this code to do this?

Comment: what's this `Properties`? is it an array? what does the `put` do?  you need to explain the object that you want to sort then I can show you how.

Comment: I have modified the code to present it here. The actual variables and values are specific to our environment. I have replaced everything with generic examples. Please ignore any variable name error. I changed the names to put it here.

Comment: You've got some  `Properties` class which you haven't shown the structure of. The easiest way to achieve what you want is probably to add a `sort` method to that class, but without knowing how the class properties are organised it's impossible to say how you should do that.

Comment: The classes are provided by vRO. I cannot make changes to it. Any other way? We are using the vRealize Suite. This task comes under vRO https://www.vmware.com/in/products/vrealize-orchestrator.html